# Does ObjectBox have advanced caching?

Tags: objectbox

Here is the use case: we need to limit the amount of RAM use to N Mb and the objects memory consumption is much higher (let's say 10N Mb). We should be able to find a `String` value for the `String` key (map) as simple example.

So we'd prefer to respect our memory constraint and loose in performance and we assume some advanced caching strategy should be used.

Does Object support some advanced caching? Can we explicitly set the limit of RAM used and still work?

PS. As some alternatives we consider using more compact data structures (trie for example) taking into account we know the nature of our data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice thing about ObjectBox is that it does not do caching - it delegates that to the operating system. The OS usually knows very well how to optimize memory among processes according to their usage patterns.

The underlying technology is called memory mapping (e.g. [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on Linux). Simplified, it makes data on disk available in RAM and thus serves as an excellent cache. The management is completely up to the OS, which you could consider as an "advanced cache" to come back to your question. In short, it automatically uses more memory if available. And it can operate using very little memory. Thus, there is no need to limit the cache.

Adding to this is the fact that ObjectBox itself consumes very little resources (CPU & RAM), and thus leaves more RAM for caching compared to traditional databases.

Regarding tries: if you are heavily relying on string storage/look up, this is a valid alternative if space used on disk is a concern. As always, it depends on your use case.

Comment: i guess this delegation can play against us and can easily become a disadvantage due to lack of control. However thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can you give an example of when more control would be advantageous?

Comment: yup, fine-grained control like cache size, invalidation time, RAM/objects count setting. Also it will affect performance since disk reading/flushing takes time to having of performance predictability would help

Comment: There are two sides to this. On the one hand, setting an upper bound for caching is an artificial limitation wasting further caching potential. On the other, cache control can "reserve" a minimum set of caching resources that cannot be "stolen" by other processes. Is that what you have in mind?